# Ruby on Rails tutorial: section 6.3 -- unknown attribute error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I am working my way through Michael Hartl's tutorial (an excellent tutorial!) and I have hit a block in chapter 6, section 6.3 Adding a Secure Password.

The tutorial says "add *password* and *password_confirmation* to the Users model ... the password attributes will be *virtual*" -- which is probably why there is no migration to add them to the database schema.

However, unless they are added to the end of the attr_accessible line in user.rb, I get a MassAssignmentSecurity error, but when I add them I get an

```
UnknownAttributeError:
   unknown attribute: password
```

The user.rb code on github has the attributes added to attr_accessible but the rest of the code (in user_spec.rb too) is the same excluding that which I imagine is added in later chapters.

I have gone through this chapter a second time, starting from scratch, thinking it was my mistake but it persists...

The gems installed are

```
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using multi_json (1.3.2) 
Using activesupport (3.2.3) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using activemodel (3.2.3) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.3) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.3) 
Using actionpack (3.2.3) 
Using mime-types (1.18) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.3) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.33) 
Using activerecord (3.2.3) 
Using activeresource (3.2.3) 
Using addressable (2.2.7) 
Using annotate (2.4.1.beta1) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) 
Using bootstrap-sass (2.0.0) 
Using nokogiri (1.5.2) 
Using ffi (1.0.11) 
Using childprocess (0.3.2) 
Using libwebsocket (0.1.3) 
Using rubyzip (0.9.8) 
Using selenium-webdriver (2.21.2) 
Using xpath (0.1.4) 
Using capybara (1.1.2) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.3.1) 
Using execjs (1.3.1) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.7.0) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.2.3) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using diff-lcs (1.1.3) 
Using guard (1.0.1) 
Using guard-rspec (0.5.5) 
Using spork (0.9.0) 
Using guard-spork (0.3.2) 
Using jquery-rails (2.0.0) 
Using libnotify (0.5.9) 
Using bundler (1.1.3) 
Using rails (3.2.3) 
Using rb-inotify (0.8.8) 
Using rspec-core (2.9.0) 
Using rspec-expectations (2.9.1) 
Using rspec-mocks (2.9.0) 
Using rspec (2.9.0) 
Using rspec-rails (2.9.0) 
Using sass (3.1.16) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.5) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.5) 
Using uglifier (1.2.3)
```

Thanks for any help or pointers to my next step,

Chris

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem when following the tutorial, then I noticed I had forgotten to add a call to `has_secure_password` below the `attr_accessible` call in `app/models/user.rb`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  // rest of the code
end
```

The `UnknownAttributeError` was gone and all tests passed after I did it.

Answer (score 1):

You can defined virtual attributes in your model like this:

```
attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which sub-section of 6.3 your are in, the tests may be failing.  They should fail first and then you start 'fixing' them by adding code.  In 6.3.4, you fix the problem you are describing by adding `has_secure_password` to the user.rb

Answer (score 0):

after modifying the user.rb file with attribute accessible for password and password_confirmaton

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  .
  .
  .
end
```

**don't forget to save it!**